# trying to create a matrix in ruby

Tags: ruby, matrix

i have a file called terain.dat which contains this matrix:

```
10
1 1 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 12 12 12
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 12 12 12
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 12 12 12
```

i want to read in the file and use the first number on the first line as the size of the matrix (which is 10 X 10 in this case). And then fill the 10 X 10 matrix with the numbers below.

this is what i have so far:

```
    class Terrain     

              def initialize file_name

              @input = IO.readlines(file_name) #read in file  # reads in the file with the terrain detials
              @matrix_size =  @input[0].to_i  # changes the first index to an int (so i can make a10X10 matrix)
              @land = Matrix.[@matrix_size, @matrix_size]  # will this make a 10 X 10 matrix??

           end
  end
```

i was wondering if this will make a 10X10 matrix and how do i fill it??

Answer (score 3):

actually no. The `Matrix.[]` is used for setting the values of a row.
So `Matrix.[10,10]` would create a Matrix with 2 rows, and in each column a 10.

What you are searching for is `Matrix.build(row_size, column_size)` where `column_size` defaults to `row_size`. This gives you an enumerator which you can use to set the values. (or you just pass a block to `Matrix.build`

I'd suggest a different approach:

```
arr = []
@input.each_index do |index|
  arr[index] = @input[index].split ' ' 
end
@land = Matrix.build(10,10) do |row, column|
  arr[row][column].to_i
end
```

Comment: how would you use the enumerator?  I'm trying to use Matrix.build(10,10)

Answer (score 3):

I'd write:

```
terrain = open("terrain.data") do |file|
  size = file.lines.first.to_i
  rows = file.lines.first(size).map { |line| line.split.map(&:to_i) }
  Matrix.rows(rows)
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You could skip over the first line, read the other lines, chomp them to remove the new lines and then split on white space. This will give you an array of arrays, which you can feed to [Matrix.rows](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.2/libdoc/matrix/rdoc/Matrix.html#method-c-rows).

Answer (score 0):

No need to declare the size. Try the following:

```
class Terrain     
  attr_accessor :m
    def initialize file_name
      data = IO.readlines(file_name)
      data.each_line do |l|
        data << l.split.map {|e| e.to_i}
      end
      @m = Matrix[*@data]
   end
end
```

Or, even better:

```
class Terrain     
  attr_accessor :m
    def initialize file_name
      File.open(file_name).each do |l|
        data << l.split.map {|e| e.to_i}
      end
      @m = Matrix[*@data]
   end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

No need for the size:

```
class Terrain     
  def initialize(file_name)
    File.open(file_name) do |f|
      @m = Matrix[*f.lines.map { |l| l.split.map(&:to_i) }]
    end
  end
end
```