# Convert contents of an array to int

Tags: ruby, int, type-conversion

I need to read in a file of which contains a list of numbers.

This code reads in the file and puts it into a 2d array. Now I need to get the average of all the numbers in my array but I need to change the contents of the array to int. Any ideas where to put the `to_i` method?

```
Class Terrain
    def initialize file_name
        @input = IO.readlines(file_name) #read in file
        @size = @input[0].to_i
        @land = [@size]

        x = 1
        while x <= @size
          @land << @input[x].split(/\s/)
          x += 1
        end
        #puts @land
    end
end
```

Comment: what happened with your previous question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7993821. It's very similar, yet you gave there no feedback, no comments, no votes, nothing. Solutions there showed how to use map yet you keep using a non-idiomatic while in this question.

Comment: To complement @tokland's comment, it's perfectly acceptable to ask for clarification in the comments if you don't understand an answer.

Answer (score 12):

Just map your array to integers:

```
@land << @input[x].split(/\s/).map(&:to_i)
```

**side note**

If you want to get the average of a line, you can do the following:

```
values = @input[x].split(/\s/).map(&:to_i)
@land << values.inject(0.0) {|sum, item| sum + item} / values.size
```

or use the following, as [Marc-André](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8279/marc-andre-lafortune) kindly pointed out in the comments:

```
values = @input[x].split(/\s/).map(&:to_i)
@land << values.inject(0.0, :+) / values.size
```

Comment: Better and faster to user `inject(0.0, :+)`

Comment: I was curious about the "faster" part and did a quick benchmark (summing a 1..1000000 array). Using `:+` is about 10% faster.

Answer (score -2):

did you try

```
@land << @input[x].split(/\s/).strip.to_i
```